# What is the new command for AffineMap?

Tags: programming

`AffineMap` was present in *Mathematica* version 4. What is the equivalent command in the current version of *Mathematica*?

Comment: "AffineTransform[m] 
gives a TransformationFunction that represents an affine transform that maps r to m.r. " ??

Comment: [AffineTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AffineTransform.html) might be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can find most packages that shipped with Mathematica but don't any more at the Wolfram Library Archive.

`AffineMap` is from a package accompanying the book Programming in Mathematica by Roman Maeder that also shipped with Mathematica 4.  It can be downloaded [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3792/).

As people mentioned in comments, it may be more convenient to use the new built in [AffineTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AffineTransform.html) function.